# CSS: Changing background makes the image and text change its color

Tags: css

I tried to use a code from [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/chadsteverson/pen/flrih?editors=110) to make my background switching. But after adding the code into my CSS file, the colors of the images and text is switching, and the background doesn´t change at all.

I placed the code for the body element.

How can I fix my site, so that it shows only the background color switching?

```html
<html>


<head>


  <link rel='stylesheet' id='child-theme-css' href='http://vocaloid.de/wp-content/themes/Vuturize/style.css?ver=2.1.2' type='text/css' media='all' />


</head>

<body class="home blog logged-in header-full-width full-width-content" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <div class="site-container">

    <div class="site-inner">
      <div class="one-half start postpreview">
        <img width="750" height="256" src="http://vocaloid.de/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/KAITO-6th-anniversary-2015-Project-DIVA-Arcade-Diamond-Dust-750x256.jpg" class="attachment-Beitragsbild wp-post-image" alt="KAITO 6th anniversary 2015 Project DIVA Arcade Diamond Dust"
        />
        <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="http://vocaloid.de/news/test/" rel="bookmark">TEST</a></h2> 

      </div>
      <div class="soc fb"><a href="http://vocaloid.de/out/facebook" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
      </div>
      <div class="soc tw"><a href="http://vocaloid.de/out/twitter" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
      </div>
</div></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your markup is not valid, you are missing two closing `div` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, in order to animate the background, you animate the `filter` property. But that property affects all content, not only the background, so the text color also changes.

Instead, you could animate `background-image`. But there is a problem: the spec defines `background-image` as non-animatable. However, webkit supports it.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted the CSS as well, but I will go ahead and try to answer the question.

One option is to make sure you only target the `background-color` inside of your `@keyframes hue` like so:

```
@keyframes hue {
    /*hue will animate from 0 to 360. Saturation and Lightness remain constant*/
    20% {background-color: hsl(72, 100%, 50%);}
    40% {background-color: hsl(144, 100%, 50%);}
    60% {background-color: hsl(216, 100%, 50%);}
    80% {background-color: hsl(288, 100%, 50%);}
    100% {background-color: hsl(360, 100%, 50%);}
}
```

view this example [here](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/animating-css3-gradients)

If you are strictly using the code from [this codepen.io](http://codepen.io/chadsteverson/pen/flrih?editors=110) then the trick is to style the text/ images after your background animation like this:

```
a {
  color: #ffff !important;
}

img {
  background: none !important;
}
```

Which is not recommended because use of `!important` is considered a temporary fix and not good CSS practice.

Comment: switching background to background color makes the css invalid. If I change the background-color of your code to background, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening because you might be changing the `color` instead of the `background-color`.